# Schedule file download in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, web-scraping

How can I order Django App to check for a file (in the link) every day and download it if some conditions are met. Let' say, in a pseudo-code:

```
every 24h
access link
if filename differs from the name of the existing file (e.g. previously downloaded)  OR there's no such a file 
download file
else skip
```

I'd be glad for the simplest solution. Maybe a tutorial?
Thanks !

PS I want it to be implemented into django app, so please **do not** suggest using *cron*

Comment: Both answers are fine and work. Another, very similar option is python-rq(.org), possibly by means of django-rq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for my problem - hope it helps someone else!

Firstly - According to the doc (https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) fi installed `django-background-tasks` and added it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. Then, database migration was performed.

Now, the main step - in the App's folder I created `tasks.py` when I put my function, proceeding it with a decorator (in my problem it was `@background(schedule=10)`. Then, the function call was set in the `urls.py` ! This is crucial, since inserting it into `settings.py` cause some problems with a PRIVATE_KEY.

Finally, `python manage.py process_tasks` and `python manage.py runserver` et voila. It does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use celery. But, if you want something  simpler,  django-background-tasks is  easiest option. https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

It's as easy as this:

Adding decorator in your function

```
@background
def your_function(..) //all logic resides here
```

Calling function: This code resides where you need to make the function call start( maybe after some object is created?, or in settings.py if it has to start without any condition.

```
your_function(....,repeat=TASK.DAILY, repeat_until=<datetime or None>)
```

Comment: The easiest option is exactly what I'm looking for. So inserting it into settings.py will launch function at the start of the server?

Comment: Great, however I have a problem!
According to the website (https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) I added `background_task` to the INSTALLED_APPS, performed migration, created a file tasks.py in my app directory where I placed a function with @background(schedule=60) decorator. In the settings I import it via from app.tasks import scheduledJob... but then server doesn't start! Got an error - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty. - though it is no empty.

Comment: I think it is a circular dependency. Don't create tasks.py. Place the function in settings.py itself.

Comment: I did that at the beginning. Nevertheless, then the following problem occurs: "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."

Comment: Did you try puting your function and the call after INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yep, the function is put in the end of the settings.py

Comment: Please, take a look at the gist: https://gist.github.com/farmaceut/ad0d48d6474fff0524ed503cf6358c70

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219099/discussion-between-farmaceut-and-sagar-adhikari).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django package [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to perform scheduled tasks.

Follow the documentation and using '*celery beat*' you can set up a periodic task.

Your scenario would be as followed:

```py
from celery.schedules import crontab

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes every day at midnight
    'run-every-day': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=0),
    },
}
```